# Android picture naming convention

Tags: samsung, stock-android, photos, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I am using Samsung Galaxy S5 from T-Mobile.

I noticed that pictures are named as

**YYYMMDD_ABCDEF.jpg**

where the first part represents date and the last purt I suspect represents time in military format. This is very convenient but it would be more convenient if I could choose to name my files like

**YYYY-MM-DD_ABCDED.jpg**

automatically.

Does anyone know how to change default picture file naming convention in Samsung Galaxy S5 / Android ?

Comment: AFAIK, this cannot be changed. The naming pattern is dependent upon the camera app. For example, I use the [Google Camera app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.GoogleCamera) and the files are named `YYYY-MM-DD HH.mm.ss.jpg`

Comment: I can confirm this. Having used different camera apps, file names were specific to them (and patterns different).